# How to work out if useCallback will be worth it or even better for performance at all?

Tags: reactjs

I know what `useCallback` does and that sometimes you need it for reference equality. However in my situation it would just be an optional performance optimisation. This is for a React Native project and the app will be used on some low spec devices.

How can I work out if it will be an improvement (I know sometimes that it is not: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback), or if the improvement would be so minor as to not be worth it?

`timeFormatted` is the function that I'm considering wrapping in a `useCallback`:

```
  const timeFormatted = (() => {
    if (!time) return null;
    const [hour, min] = time.split(':');
    return moment()
      .hour(+hour)
      .minutes(+min)
      .seconds(0);
  })();
  
  return(
    <InputDatePicker
      value={timeFormatted?.unix()}
    />
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I don't think using useCallback would improve anything, however I recommend using [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) instead of moment to improve bundle size and performance

Comment: I agree moment wasnt a great choice but outside of my control sadly. Can you expand on why useCallback wouldnt improve here?

Comment: well, keep in mind that nothing is free...using useCallback have a cost also but make sense if your function contains huge logic, lot of if or map or so, in this case you evaluate it only when your deps change. actually you are just creating a date (yes using moment ) but is not that much.

Comment: you can still try to profiler your function if you want to check exactly the performance